# How to view chm file in a web browser?

Tags: html, css, chm, helpfile, helpndoc

I have a CHM file created in HelpNDoc application.

Now in a browser page that I created I have a help option in navigation. When I click this help option I want the CHM file to show in the browser.

How can I do this?

Comment: The CHM file is self-contained with it's own viewer. You simply open the CHM file, but it is possible to open the CHM file to a given topic. I do this. The alternative is to do a HTML build of your help and upload that to your domain. Then, that build will show in your preferred browser.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to save your docs as a so called web-based help and upload to your web server. HelpNDoc projects can be exported to help files like CHM and as a web site too.

From the main menu  use:

- Home > Generate help > HTML documentation

HTML Help 1.x (CHM) does not have the capability of delivering compressed help over http. You can point to a .chm on the user's local drive, and you can link to a .chm for download, but that's as far as it goes. You may want to zip your *.chm files for download.

Please note that the proprietary CHM file format is normally generated by Micosoft HH Workshop (hhw.exe). It’s 25 years old und was first shipped with IE4 and Windows 95. The CHM help file format is deep integrated to the Windows operating system and outdated.

The ability to look inside an ITS (CHM) file is something unique to the old Microsoft Internet Explorer only. Only IE could load a locally path.